# How to use many to many polymorphic relation in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am reading laravel 5.2 docs to implement many to many polymorphic relation in my Laravel Application.
I have Many models like `Blog`, `Question`, `Photo` etc and I want to have Tagging system for all of them.
I have created Tag table with following schema

```
  Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('slug')->unique();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Below is pivot table schema. Pivot table name is `entity_tags`

```
Schema::create('entity_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();;
     $table->integer('taggable_id')->unsigned();
     $table->string('taggable_type');
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->index('tag_id');
     $table->index('taggable_id');
     $table->index('taggable_type');
});
```

This is the relationship defined in `Tag` model for `Question` model

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Question', 'entity_tags', 'tag_id', 'taggable_id');
}
```

And the following relation is defined in `Question` Model

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'entity_tags', 'taggable_id', 'tag_id');
}
```

Now I want to define Many to Many Polymorphic relationship as defined in Laravel 5.2.
My Question are

- how I can define them?
- Should I remove the Many to Many
  relationship and only define Many to Many polymorphic relationship ?
  If yes, then how to manage custom pivot table name ?
- Also is it required to suffix column name with word `able` that are part of
  polymorphic relationship ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Use return $this->morphToMany() instead of belongsToMany, and in the Tag model, write 3 methods with return $this->morphedByMany() for the reverse relationship.
- You only need polymorphic definitions, no need for the many to many normal ones. The name of the pivot table is with 'able' at the end by the default convention but you can name it anything you want.
- no, you don't have to have a word with 'able' at the end, it's just a way to define that it's something more general, you can name it anything you want.

Naming is based on some default convention by Laravel.

Update:

You have the following pivot table schema:

```
Schema::create('entity_tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();;
        $table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('entity_type');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->index('tag_id');
        $table->index('entity_id');
        $table->index('entity_type');
});
```

and the tags table:

```
Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('slug')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

So you want to create the relationships for blog, video and question tables / models:

Tag.php Model:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Question', 'entity', 'entity_tags');
}

public function blogs()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Blog', 'entity', 'entity_tags');
}

public function videos()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Video', 'entity', 'entity_tags');
}
```

Question.php / Blog.php / Video.php

```
public function tags()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\Tag', 'entity', 'entity_tags');
}
```

Comment: I tried the solution but below is the error, when I was saving a new question
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tagz_type' in 'where clause' (SQL: select 'entity_type' from 'entity_tags' where 'entity_id' = 4 and 'tagz_type' = App\Question)`

I think the second parameter should be `xyz`

Comment: One more thing, instead of `xyz_id` and `xyz_type`, I have used `entity_id` and `entity_type`